# Why does execve not start a process?

Tags: c, process, fork

I wrote for uni a method, which should start a program. I have to use execve. But it doesn't work. For example, when I use execvp instead of execve it works and starts the program.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

pid_t run_command(char **argv, int no_fork){
    extern char **environ;
    pid_t pid;


    if(no_fork != 0){
        execve(*argv, argv, environ);
        return 0;
    }
    else{
        if((pid = fork()) < 0){
            printf("Error: fork!\n");
            return -1;
        }
        else if(pid == 0){

            argv++;

            printf("execve(%s)\n", *argv);
            execve(*argv, argv, environ);

        }
        else {                                  
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }
    return pid;
}

/*
int run_cmdline(char ** argv){
    return 0;
}*/

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    run_command(argv, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiling:

clang -o main shell.c

For example execute:

./main firefox

should start firefox. With execvp and without environ it works, but not with execve.

Thx for any help :)

Comment: if `execve` is failing, then it falls through to the next line where you should be able to print an error message indicating what happened. `perror("could not execve");` would be a good start.

Comment: could not execve: Bad address

Comment: Is your program also required to search the PATH for the executable (only if it contains no `/` characters), or is it the responsibility of the user of the program to supply a valid pathname?

Answer (score 2):

> execve(*argv, argv, environ);
>
> ./main firefox

`execve` does not search PATH. You have to provide full path to the executable or resolve the path yourself. The reference for this behavior is in [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), but I find it hard to read, [man execve](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execvpe) looks easier to me.

So something like:

```
./main /usr/bin/firefox
```

should work, or even:

```
./main /usr/bin/sh -c firefox
```

Or maybe just use `execvp` which takes the "parent" `environ` auto-magically and also searches path. There is also linux extension `execvpe` which is not in posix and does take `environ`.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `run_command` with `main`'s argument list. Since the program you want to run and its arguments are in `argv[1]` onwards, you need to check that `argc` is at least 2, then call `run_command(argv + 1, 0)`.

EDIT

It seems that `run_command` itself increments `argv`, but only in one of the two code paths that calls `execve` for some reason. The two code paths should treat the argument list consistently. Personally, I think it is better for the caller to arrange for `run_command`s `argv[0]` to refer to the program it is supposed to run.

If you insist on incrementing `argv` in `run_command` itself so that its `*argv` refers to the program to be run, then you need to check that `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` are both non-null before you increment `argv`. If the caller is responsible for making `run_command`s `*argv` refer to the program to be run, then it's a good idea to check that `*argv` is non-null anyway.

Comment: but I do argv++ in else if condition. So I guess that is not the mistake.

Comment: @JanWolfram I never spotted that. Why does it treat the argument list differently for the "fork" and "no-fork" paths? You still need to check `argc`.

Comment: I didn't finished no-for but it should be also argv++. I want to start new childprocess if no-fork is not 0

Comment: @JanWolfram The other thing is that `execve` does not search the path (you'd need to call `execvpe` instead for that), so unless there is an executable called "firefox" in the current directory, `./main firefox` wouldn't work.

Comment: @JanWolfram If you insist on `run_command` being responsible for incrementing `argv`, you should at least check that both `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` are non-null before you increment it.